# MacBook Pros WiFi doesn't turn "on"

Tags: wifi

I have a MacBook Pro 13" 2015 (v10.14.3). When logging in (after startup) I can see the "looking for WiFi networks" icon on the menu bar. Shortly after it turns off.

In `System Preferences.app` I can press the `turn WiFi on` button, but it  does nothing.

Weird circumstances mentioning. We had some severe internet issues yesterday and my internet provider *fixed it*. Not sure what that means, or if that has anything to do with my issue as my macbook can connect to the browser, but not the Mail app. iPad connects without any issue. (I believe this problem is on my Mac.) Note that this is the only mac computer (with some iOS devices) in the network.

Comment: If you restart your router/WiFi device, can you connect then? If not afterwards, can you go into System Preferences > Network > WiFi > Advanced, and remove your network settings and reconnect?

Comment: restarted Rotuer, no difference. (all other devices work) currently waiting for apple support to get back to me while computer is rebooting in safe mode. (Though it looks to me like it's frozen, but I'm won't touch it until I hear from their callback.)

Comment: This question reminds me of several years ago when many people with iPhone 4S had their WiFi stop working. (For me, it would be able to work very briefly and then become disabled again; making the phone cold may have helped slightly.) Perhaps there is a hardware issue on the AirPort card and it needs to be replaced?

Comment: @kai-al. Thanks for thought. I got a ethernet cable, so the immediate issue of connectivity is for now resolved.